# javascript populate iframe, modify source in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Populating the contents of 2 iframes with the same HTML preview. Although for one of the iframes I need to modify the data/html by removing the images.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data){
            var iframe = document.getElementById('preview');
            iframe.parentNode.style.display = "block";                      
            iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
            iframe.document.open();
            iframe.document.write(data);
            iframe.document.close();

            var iframe = document.getElementById('preview-noimgs');
            iframe.parentNode.style.display = "block";                      
            iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
            iframe.document.open();

            var $data = $(data);
            $data.find("img").removeAttr("src");

            iframe.document.write($data.html());
            iframe.document.close();
        }
    }
});
```

This gives me: `NULL` or `[object Object]` depending if I add `.html()`

What is the correct way to modify the source?

Reading through the jquery docs I found `parseHTML()` but sadly wont be able to use this because we are restricted to version 1.7.1 is there another way to do this?

Preview: http://jsbin.com/cuqarica/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that `.html()` returns the **innerHTML**, not the outerHTML

I think you should try this instead:

```
var $data = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");
```

By adding a div wrapper, you can be sure that `$data.html()` returns the correct original node.

If you're adding a full html page to the iframe, you could try this:

```
iframe = document.getElementById('preview-noimgs');
iframe.parentNode.style.display = "block";                      
var iframeWindow = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
iframeWindow.document.open();
iframeWindow.document.write(data);
iframeWindow.document.close();

$(iframe).contents().find("html").find("img").removeAttr("src"); //remove the `src`
```

Comment: My data is full HTML with doctype, could this be the reason jquery is having issues

Comment: I think I need to make sure we modify the data before writing to the iframe. Jquery has had issues in the past modifying an iframe. I'm just a bit lost on what to try next.

Comment: @John Magnolia: a mistake, it should be `$(iframe).contents().find("html").find("img").removeAttr("src");`. I updated the answer

Comment: I think there may be restrictions with dealing with content within an iFrame, you could use a service like php or ajax to download the origional page as text, strip the img tags etc then display the html.